# getting OEMBED object to return instead of undefined using Twit for Node

Tags: node.js, twitter, oembed

So i am using Twit https://github.com/ttezel/twit for Node

i would like to get the OEMBED code from the twitter 1.1 api , but it does not seem to work.

```
twit.get('statuses/oembed', { id: 133640144317198338 },  function (err, data, response) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(err);

        })
```

So I just keep getting undefined returned back to me, the url pattern seems correct but i do not know why it is not working.

Here is the error that is logged

```
{ [Error: Sorry, that page does not exist]
  message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist',
  statusCode: 404,
  code: 34,
  allErrors: [ { message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist', code: 34 } ],
  twitterReply: '{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}' }
```

I am able to retrieve statues and pretty much everything else, but oembed will not work.

Any HELP would be great

Here is the link to OEMBED api for twitter https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/oembed.json?id=240192632003911681

Answer (score 1):

Wrap some quotes around your Tweet ID. I ran into this because I was feeding in a status's `id`, not `id_str`.

Answer (score 0):

Insert some quotes around your Tweet ID.